# DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE no funciona con cursores

Tags: plsql

Si ejecuto esta linea, muestra perfectamente la salida del DBMS
`BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('HOLA');
END;`

pero al ejecutar este proceso

`DECLARE
  CURSOR mayor_valor IS
    SELECT nombre, descripcion
    FROM producto
    WHERE precio = (SELECT MAX(precio) FROM producto);
BEGIN
  FOR maximo IN mayor_valor LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Producto con mayor precio: ' ||maximo.nombre);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Descripcion: ' || maximo.descripcion);
  END LOOP;
END;`

solo me sale

Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.

Este bloque me funciono perfectamente en una sala de computadores de la universidad, pero no aqui en mi casa. También tengo otro archivo que contiene un paquete con 2 procedimientos, y al ejecutar estos, la salida del DBMS funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estas con SQL Developer tienes que activar la salida DBMS que esta en el menú ver.

Luego tienes que establecer conexión con el servidor de ORACLE, (Igual que lo haces para establecer una conexión con la base de datos pulsando el botón +) luego te quedara algo tal que así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Hola Juan Jesús y bienvenido! Aunque la respuesta es buena no estaría de más explicar el proceso para activar esta opción (con imágenes o un paso a paso).

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que muestras es correcto, sin embargo no indicas si lo estas ejecutando desde consola o desde algun IDE como Toad, Navigator.

Si estas usando TOAD en la pestaña DBMS Output te saldra todo resultado

Comment: Yo trabajo en SQL developner. En la pestaña ver se abre una salida para el DBMS, la abro añado una salida y el primer código funciona normal, se imprime hola en la salida del DBMS, pero en el segundo código con cursores, no pasa nada. Ese código lo escribí en otro cumputador y funcionaba ahí, pero en el mio no.

Answer (score 0):

Habilitando el serveroutput:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
...
```

se redirijen los mensajes que generan los DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE a la salida del script.